# Why min and max range method does not return valid output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to have a method which needs to check in the valid range between `-064.000000 to -180.000000` and `142.000000 to 180.000000`. The ranges object that I have looks like the following:

```
"ranges": {
  "range1": {
    "min": -180,
    "max": -64
  },
  "range2": {
    "min": 142,
    "max": 180
  }
}
```

So far, this is what I was able to complete but it doesn't seem to work right:

```
const mustBeInRangeInclusive = ({ userInput, ranges }) => {
  let data_num = _.toNumber(userInput);
  for (let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    return result = data_num >= ranges[i][0] && data_num <= ranges[i][1];
  }
};
```

Can someone please help me complete this method to figure out what am I doing wrong?

**Expected output:**

```
-63 -> invalid
-64: valid
181 -> invalid
180: valid
141 -> invalid
142: valid
```

Comment: You are treating objects like arrays, this is not how it works, please read [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: @rksh1997 thanks for noticing that - fixed my post.

Comment: you are still doing it here `data_num >= ranges[i][0] && data_num <= ranges[i][1];` But any way you don't need `range1` and `range2` put `min` and `max` directly and access them the right way.

Comment: Is there a reason `ranges` is an object rather than an array? If possible converting it to an array would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - can you please help me out by showing me an example with an array? I am still a newbie trying to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer based upon the [comment request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002719/why-min-and-max-range-method-does-not-return-valid-output?noredirect=1#comment111413321_63002719) of OP, and does not solve the issue if `filters` would be an object.

Assuming you can change the definition, using an array of filters would be a lot easier to work with than an object with filters. You can use the array [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check if every elements matches a criteria. Use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if some (one or more) elements matches a criteria.

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("user-input");

const ranges = [ // <- changed definition to an array
  { "min":  0, "max": 100 },
  { "min": 50, "max": 150 },
];

userInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const nr = parseInt(userInput.value, 10);
  
  const coversNr = ({min, max}) => min <= nr && nr <= max;
  
  const withinEveryRange = ranges.every(coversNr);
  const withinSomeRange  = ranges.some(coversNr);
  
  console.log("withinEveryRange //=>", withinEveryRange);
  console.log("withinSomeRange  //=>", withinSomeRange );
});
```

```html
<input id="user-input" type="number" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot and worked like a charm. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Few edits, as the question code keeps changing a bit.

**First problem - accessing objects properties**

If you have an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), you access its values by indeces.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
let firstItem = array[0];
let secondItem = array[1];
```

If you have object, you access its propeties by their names.

```js
let someObject = { 'name': 'John', 'age': 21 };
let name = someObject.name;
name = someObject['name'];
```

If you have array of objects, you combine both methods.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [
    { 'name': 'John', 'age': 21 },
    { 'name': 'Sam', 'age': 23 }
]
let firstObjectsName = arrayOfObjects[0].name;
```

**Second problem - exiting the loop on the first iteration**
You call `return` statement as soon as you enter the loop making it impossible to enter the second iteration. You could store result of each iteration in the array and return it in the end.

```js
const mustBeInRangeInclusive = ({ userInput, ranges }) => {
  let results = [];
  let data_num = _.toNumber(userInput);
  for (let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    results.push(data_num >= ranges[i].min && data_num <= ranges[i].max);
  }

  return results;
};
```

Comment: mcjmzn, I tested your method using the following structure that I currently have in the question but it doesn't seem to work properly. The code is taking `-64` as an invalid input whereas it should have accept it that becuase it's in the range of the first scenario.

Comment: The code above return an array of boolean values indicating whether the input number is within range or not. So results[i] tells you if the number is in ranges[i].

Comment: looks like it never goes into the for loop. I just confirmed again.